# Pandas groupby with pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the following dataframe
[image]

The **chr** column is for chromosome number and **pos** is for the specific position in it. The **pos** column is sorted in ascending order. I need to split each chromosome into equal bins of 100, 1000, 10000, etc. E.g. for bin value 100 chr 1 would be splitted into bins [0, 100), [100, 200), ... [*last position*, *last position*+100).

So (probably) I need to first *group_by* **chr** column, and then use *pd.cut* on **pos** columns with bins determined by max **pos** in a group. How do I do this?

I only can find examples with set bins, e.g

```
pd.groupby(['chr', pd.cut(df_sorted.pos, bins=100)])
```

But in my case I need to determine last bin interval by group max **pos** value.

I've tried this:

```
chr_group = df_sorted.groupby(['chr'])

chr_group.apply(lambda grp: pd.cut(grp.pos, bins=pd.interval_range(
    start=0, freq=1000, end=grp.pos.max(), closed='left')))
```

But this gives me error
`ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

**Note**: dataset is almost 3m rows, can't use cycles

Comment: Note: ```adding df_sorted.fillna(0, inplace=True)``` doesn't help

Comment: Maybe adding `.fillna(0)` at the end of lambda function would help?

Comment: you mean ```chr_group.apply(lambda grp: pd.cut(grp.pos, bins=pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=1000, end=grp.pos.max(), closed='left'))).fillna(0) ```  or ```chr_group.apply(lambda grp: pd.cut(grp.pos, bins=pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=1000, end=grp.pos.max(), closed='left')).fillna(0))``` ?

Comment: The second one. But also it would be fine if you added the text version of dataframe, not a picture.

Comment: Doing this gives ```ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first```

Answer (score 0):

Yay, I finally managed it. What I needed to do was to extend the bin interval border. The error was caused by last rows that were not covered by bin intervals

```
chr_group = df_sorted.groupby(['chr'])
chr_group.apply(lambda grp: pd.cut(grp.pos, bins=pd.interval_range(
    start=0, freq=1000, end=grp.pos.max()+1000, closed='left')))
```